# Kernel of a matrix with polynomial entries

Tags: commutative-algebra

What is the most direct method to calculate the kernel of a matrix $A\in k [x_1,\dots,x_l]^{n\times m}$, $k$ being a field? What is the most direct method to calculate its Hilbert series? Is one obliged to use Gröbner bases?

Comment: [http://www.unimelb-macaulay2.cloud.edu.au/](http://www.unimelb-macaulay2.cloud.edu.au/)

Comment: I know about M2. I want to do the calculations by hand in the most direct way.